# Удалить словарь по значению

Tags: python, dict

Имеется список словарей:

```
a = [{"word": "c", "count": 4}, {"word": "dog", "count": 2}, {"word": "_restore", "count": 1}, {"word": "-f", "count": 5}....]
```

Необходимо удалить те словари, в которых значение длины ключа "word" равно 1 и первый символ равен одному из этих знаков ['-', '_']

Пробовала реализовать это следующим образом, но выводит список без изменений

```
sp = []
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    if len(a[i]['word']) == 1 or a[i]['word'][0] in ['-', '_']:
        del a[i]
```

Comment: Длина ключа = 1 это включая символ `-` или `_` или без учёта него?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

лучше не удалять из списка, а собрать список заново:

```
a = [{"word": "c", "count": 4}, {"word": "dog", "count": 2}, {"word": "_restore", "count": 1}, {"word": "-f", "count": 5}]

a = [obj for obj in a if len(obj['word']) != 1 and obj['word'][0] not in ('_', '-')]

print(a)
```

кроме того у вас в условии написано **И** (`в которых значение длины ключа "word" равно 1 и первый символ равен одному из этих знаков ['-', '_']`), а в коде **ИЛИ**

я в примере привел вариант с **ИЛИ**

Но поскольку я не удаляю, а собираю список с нужными элементами, то условие такое:

размер не 1 и первый символ не '-' или '_'